# Weird issue where while trying to scan data from a document instead of a space the program reads a new line in C

Tags: c

I was trying to write a code which reads data from 1 .txt file does some sort of data manipulation and writes the new data in a new .txt file. While doing so i tried to test if the data was properly being read and written so i tried to do it with the base .txt file however whenever i ran the program if the last string consisted of 2 words it would break and go into a new line.

```
typedef struct sport {
    char ime_sporta[MAXSIZE];
    int godina;
    char osvojena_medalja[MAXSIZE];
    char drzava[MAXSIZE];
} Sport;

typedef struct node {
    Sport sport;
    struct node* next;
}Node;


Node* Ucitavanje() {

    FILE* sport_medals = fopen("sport_medals.txt", "r");

    if (!sport_medals) {
        
        printf("DAT_GRESKA");
        exit(0);
    }

    Node* head = NULL, * tail = head, * tmp;
    Sport s;
    
while (fscanf(sport_medals," %[^\|]\| %d %s %s\n", s.ime_sporta, &s.godina, s.osvojena_medalja, s.drzava) == 4) {
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
        if(tmp == NULL){
            printf("MEM_GRESKA");
            exit(0);
        }
        
        tmp->sport = s;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if (!head) head = tmp;
        else tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    
        
    fclose(sport_medals);
    return head;



}

int ispis(Node* head) {
    Node* t;
    
    FILE* f = fopen("winners.txt", "w");
    if (!f) {
        printf("G3");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (head) {
        fprintf(f, "%s|%d %s %s\n", head->sport.ime_sporta, head->sport.godina, head->sport.osvojena_medalja, head->sport.drzava);
        t = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(t);
    }
    fclose(f);

}

int main() {
    Node* head;
    char trazeni_sport[MAXSIZE];
    scanf("%s",trazeni_sport);
    head = Ucitavanje();
    
    ispis(head);
    
    return 0;

}
```

the input of first 4 lines

```
Weightlifting|2008 Gold North Korea

Swimming|2008 Gold United States

Swimming|2008 Silver United States

Football|2012 Bronze South Korea
```

the output of first 4 lines

```
Weightlifting|2008 Gold North

Korea

Swimming|2008 Gold United

States

Swimming|2008 Silver United

States

Football|2012 Bronze South

Korea
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with expected output and actual output. Your posted code does not compile (missing `#include` directives, `MAXSIZE` undeclared, etc.).

Comment: In the string literal `" %[^\|]\| %d %s %s\n"`, what is the meaning of the escape sequence `\|` supposed to be? That does not seem to be a valid escape sequence on most compilers. What are you trying to accomplish with the backslash character?

Answer (score 2):

With your input:

```
Weightlifting|2008 Gold North Korea
Swimming|2008 Gold United States
```

the first iteration of the loop will read:

```
ime_sporta: Weightlifting
godina: 2008
osvojena_medalja: Gold
drzava: North
```

Only one word will be read into `drzava` because `%s` reads only until the first white-space. This will leave the read pointer just before `Korea`. On the next iteration, the `%[^|]|` will read until the first `|`, so it will read `Korea`, the new line and `Swimming`:

```
ime_sporta: Korea
Swimming
godina: 2008
osvojena_medalja: Gold
drzava: United
```

And again only one word will be read into `drzava`.

And so forth, everything as expected, nothing strange here.

Later, when you print, you put new-line after `drzava`, so after the first element is printed you end up with:

```
... North↲
```

and when the next element is printed you add to this:

```
Korea↲
Swimming ...
```

If you want to read into `drzava` everything until the end of line then replace the last `%s` with `%[^\n]`.